# Add one single point to a rChart dimple line chart

Tags: rcharts, dimple.js

I want to add one single point to a dimple line chart and have used this.

```css
vo <- (round(seq(0.5,0.6,0.001),5))
sh <- (1-((vo)^(1/3)))
sh <- 100*sh
dat <- data.frame(cbind(vo,sh))
ph <- data.frame(vo=0.55, sh=16)

d1 <- dPlot(sh~vo,
            data = dat,
            type = "line"
            ,defaultColors = "#!['blue']!#"
)
d1$yAxis('addMeasureAxis')
d1$layer(
  sh ~ vo
  ,groups = c("vo","sh")
  ,data = ph
  ,type="bubble"
)
```

As a novice I have played with all the possible solutions I could find, but ended up - at best - like this above. The point I want to add is just not where I expect him to be. Instead of showing up at the defined position, he moves up on the y-Axis.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to timeportfolio I got a nice solution. and with a little bit more help from him from other posts I was able to format the xAxis more to what I expect.
But there now show other problems up, I could not find an answer for:
1. The xAxis somehow seems to be suppressed, although the scale is visible
2. When changing the overrideMin to lets say 15, the dashed line of the tooltip goes beyond the xAxis.
Can this be changed ?

```html
d1$setTemplate(afterScript = 
  "<script>
    myChart.axes[0].shapes.selectAll('text')
        .each(function(d,i){
            // remove incrementally, so something like every 5
            if( i % 20 == 0 ) {
              //remove transform - translate and rotate
              // do other styling and manipulation here also
              d3.select(this).style('transform','')
            } else {
              d3.select(this).remove()
            }
            })
        .attr('transform','rotate()')
        .style('text-anchor','middle')
        .style('font-size','50%')
    myChart.axes[0]
          .titleShape.text('Vol')
          .style('font-size','100%')
  </script>"
)
d1
```

I have inserted just the afterScript, using the code from above and changing the overrideMin should make it clear what I mean.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You did well considering that this functionality is experimental and undocumented.  As of now, to get this to work, you will need to explicitly set the max and min on the `yAxis` in two places to get correct alignment (yes, I know it is ugly).  The complete code would be something like

```
library(rCharts)

vo <- (round(seq(0.5,0.6,0.001),5))
sh <- (1-((vo)^(1/3)))
sh <- 100*sh
dat <- data.frame(cbind(vo,sh))
ph <- data.frame(vo=0.55, sh=16)

d1 <- dPlot(sh~vo,
            data = dat,
            type = "line"
            ,defaultColors = "#!['blue']!#"
)
d1$yAxis('addMeasureAxis',overrideMin = 0, overrideMax = 30)
d1$layer(
  sh ~ vo
  ,groups = c("vo","sh")
  ,data = ph
  ,type="bubble"
  ,yAxis = d1$params$yAxis
)
d1
```

Please let me know if this works for you.  Sorry it is still so clunky.

Comment: see here for some more tests/examples https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_dimple/blob/gh-pages/nytbaseball.R

Comment: Thank you ver much, this is great. It works, though I do not exactly understand though background of it, I am happy.